# Objeto de la clase B **b

Tags: c++

Estaba leyendo una conferencia de Cristina Cachero sobre fundamentos de la programación orientada a objeto (POO), lectura muy recomendable para quien tenga un nivel intermedio de conocimientos.

El tema es que, hablando sobre la implementación de la composición utiliza tres ejemplos:

Dada una clase todo A y una clase parte B

1. La clase A tiene una relación 1 - b

```
class A {
    private:
    B b;
}
```

2. La clase A tiene una relación 10 - b

```
class A {
    private:
    B b[10];
}
```

3. La clase A tiene una relación 0...10 - b

```
class A {
    private:
    B *b[10];
    int num_b;
}
```

4. La clase A tiene una relación 0...* - b (es decir, entre 0 e infinito)

```
class A {
    private:
    B **b;
    int num_b;
}
```

Este cuarto punto es justo lo que no logro entender, ¿como se implementaría para que **b tenga un numero indeterminado de objetos b?, ¿como sería su constructor?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el ejemplo 3 estás creando un array de punteros. Teniendo en cuenta que un array decae a puntero, podrías iguarlar `b` a un puntero doble:

```
B *b[10];
B **b2 = b;
```

La única diferencia entre `b` y `b2` es que en el primer caso el número de elementos viene indicado explícitamente. Esto demuestra que el caso 4 no es más que una generalización del caso 3.

> ¿como se implementaría para que **b tenga un numero indeterminado de objetos b?

Cuando hablamos de número indeterminado no nos referimos a un número desconocido en todo momento. Solo es desconocido en tiempo de compilación. Es decir, el programa, durante su ejecución, sí que tiene que saber en todo momento cuántos es capaz de almacenar en `b`. Si este dato se desconociese se correría el riesgo de escribir en posiciones de memoria que no pertenecen al array y no te gustarían las consecuencias.

> ¿como sería su constructor?

La gracia del puntero doble es poder crear un array de punteros, de tal forma que cada elemento del array podrá estar inicializado (apuntará a un objeto válido) o no (apuntará a `nullptr`).

Crear un array de punteros es algo que podemos hacer en una línea:

```
B ** b = new B*[numeroDeElementos];
```

Llegados a este punto te diré que usar punteros crudos y gestionar memoria dinámica directamente para este tipo de casos puede no ser la mejor solución.

En vez de usar punteros dobles, puedes usar contenedores de la STL, simplificando el diseño y trasladando una parte de la lógica a un código ampliamente probado:

```
std::vector<B*> b;
```

Al usar un contenedor, dejas en mano del contenedor la gestión de la memoria dinámica y te centras en lo que a ti te interesa, que es la gestión de los elementos de la lista.